# SP2013 calendars starting with Tuesday despite Regional Settings

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-calendar

We have several calendars on our site, and a few days ago they started showing Tuesday as the first day of the week instead of Monday. Nothing changed as far as I can tell, but it's possible an update got installed automatically over the weekend.

I double-checked the regional settings for the subsite AND root site (they're both having the issue), but that appears to be set correctly:

[image]

On the actual calendars, though, the days are ordered like this:

1. Tuesday
2. Wednesday
3. Thursday
4. Friday
5. Saturday
6. Sunday
7. Monday

Ideally, I would like to remove Saturday & Sunday altogether, but at the moment I'd just settle for getting #1 back to Monday. **Has anyone run into this issue before?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your personal region settings.

Click **About Me** to open Mysite -> **Edit** your profile -> On the Edit Details page, click the ellipsis (…), and then click **Language and Region**.

[image]

[Change the personal language and region settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-your-personal-language-and-region-settings-caa1fccc-bcdb-42f3-9e5b-45957647ffd7)